# Sudden undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios5

I have a project that built and ran yesterday, but today it doesn't link.  I didn't change anything.  I don't know what would cause this.  I don't see main.o and _main that it is referring to.  Any ideas?  I tried a clean and build.  I looked at a couple of things on this site but don't see anything that's clueing me in.

```
Ld /Users/michelecleary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hackbook-dpdqkbplprywqfeflsbqlgpwbioo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hackbook.app/Hackbook normal i386
cd /Users/michelecleary/fbPic2/facebook-ios-sdk/sample/Hackbook
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/michelecleary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hackbook-dpdqkbplprywqfeflsbqlgpwbioo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/michelecleary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hackbook-dpdqkbplprywqfeflsbqlgpwbioo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/michelecleary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hackbook-dpdqkbplprywqfeflsbqlgpwbioo/Build/Intermediates/Hackbook.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hackbook.build/Objects-normal/i386/Hackbook.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40000 -o /Users/michelecleary/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hackbook-dpdqkbplprywqfeflsbqlgpwbioo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Hackbook.app/Hackbook

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
    -[HackbookAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in HackbookAppDelegate.o
    -[HackbookAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in HackbookAppDelegate.o
    -[HackbookAppDelegate application:handleOpenURL:] in HackbookAppDelegate.o
    -[HackbookAppDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in HackbookAppDelegate.o
    -[HackbookAppDelegate dealloc] in HackbookAppDelegate.o
    -[RootViewController dealloc] in RootViewController.o
  ...
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
    _main in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
    -[HackbookAppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in HackbookAppDelegate.o
    -[RootViewController fbDidExtendToken:expiresAt:] in RootViewController.o
    -[RootViewController request:didFailWithError:] in RootViewController.o
    -[APICallsViewController apiGraphUserPhotosPost] in APICallsViewController.o
    -[APICallsViewController request:didFailWithError:] in APICallsViewController.o
    -[APICallsViewController dialogCompleteWithUrl:] in APICallsViewController.o
    -[APICallsViewController dialogDidNotComplete:] in APICallsViewController.o
    ...
```

Comment: Luckily, I found an old zip file a little while ago and got it working again once I put facebook back in.  I'm not sure what happened there!

Comment: I think your answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049731/how-do-i-correct-the-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-main-linking-i